# image keeps aspect ratio only when page refreshes with display: flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox, responsive-images

I have an `<img>` inside a `<div>` with `display: flex`. The images is resizing without keeping the aspect ratio but when I reload the page it appears resized properly. Why does this happens and how can I resize the image inside a `<div>` with `display: flex` properly without refreshing the page?

Here is a .gif of the issue:

[image: gif of the issue]

Here is the code:

UPDATE: The default code snippet from stackoverflow seems to resize properly until 220px height but the reported issue happens in codepen (https://codepen.io/guizo/pen/XKPdKK?editors=1100#0) and if I open the html file on Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

```css
* {
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
html, body, div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <img src="https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/01/19/18/00/city-1150026_960_720.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Your code snippet, in full page view, scales the image down smoothly in Chrome, FF, IE 11 and (having best performance) Edge.

Comment: For horizontal resizing you'll want to use `align-items`. The default value is `stretch` which will cause your image to squish, so try `align-items: center;` or `flex-end`.

Comment: @Michael_B I didn't realize that the code was working fine on this code snipet (at least until 220px heigh). But this same code does not work on codepen or with the .html file on Chrome or Firefox. Thank you.

Comment: @hungerstar adding align-items: center or flex-end to the div didn't worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: @guizo [it does work](https://jsfiddle.net/hungerstar/oeo2ap5k/) sir. Reminder, this is a fix for horizontal squishing.

Comment: @hungerstar sorry I didn`t understood what you mean before. It does work for horizontal resizing. I would expect that justify-content: center or flex-end would have a similar result but unfortunately vertical resizing still stretches. Thank you.